# Is it possible to have only 1 implementation of IAnnotationTransformer in a project

Tags: java, annotations, testng, testng-annotation-test

Can we have more than 1 implementation of IAnnotationTransformer in a project that is using TestNG?
I'm using TestNg version 7.0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TestNG currently lets you wire in ONLY ONE implementation of `IAnnotationTransformer`. If you try to plug in multiple ones of them, the last one that got added is what will get invoked.

There's an open issue that is tracking this ask. See [GITHUB-1894](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1894).

As an alternative you can build your own composite `IAnnotationTransformer` which can be used to iterate through all the other annotation transformer instances. Here's a sample (Its available in the above mentioned github link)

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import org.testng.IAnnotationTransformer;
import org.testng.annotations.ITestAnnotation;
import org.testng.collections.Lists;
import org.testng.internal.ClassHelper;

public class CompositeTransformer implements IAnnotationTransformer {
  private static final String JVM_ARGS =
      "com.rationaleemotions.github.issue1894.Listener1, com.rationaleemotions.github.issue1894.Listener2";
  private List<IAnnotationTransformer> transformers = Lists.newArrayList();

  public CompositeTransformer() {
    // Ideally this would get a value from the command line. But just for demo purposes
    // I am hard-coding the values.
    String listeners = System.getProperty("transformers", JVM_ARGS);

    Arrays.stream(listeners.split(","))
        .forEach(
            each -> {
              Class<?> clazz = ClassHelper.forName(each.trim());
              IAnnotationTransformer transformer =
                  (IAnnotationTransformer) ClassHelper.newInstance(clazz);
              transformers.add(transformer);
            });
  }

  @Override
  public void transform(
      ITestAnnotation annotation, Class testClass, Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod) {
    for (IAnnotationTransformer each : transformers) {
      each.transform(annotation, testClass, testConstructor, testMethod);
    }
  }
}
```